# Track the highest high in a time series

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to find the highest number in a time series, in the most efficient way.
To avoid iterating through all the look back periods, I'm only iterating in case the current high number has just been discarded. I'm avoiding enqueue dequeue for the same performance reasons.

What would be a faster algorithm?

```
class Program
{
    static Random r = new Random();
    static int LookBackPeriods = 5; //(small to facilitate visual functional test). eventually could be 100 1000, but not more than 5000.
    static double High=0;
    static int HighLocation = 0;
    static int CurrentLocation = 0;
    static double[] arr = new double[LookBackPeriods];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //functional test - generate 100 numbers and check them in as you go:
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            CheckInCandidate(r.Next(10)); //in final application these will be real numbers
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A full iteration on all numbers (run only when the current high is overwritten)
    /// </summary>
    static void ReFindHighest()
    {
        High = arr[0];
        HighLocation =0
        for (int i = 1; i < LookBackPeriods; i++)
            if (arr[i] > High)
            {
                High = arr[i];
                HighLocation = i;
            }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// minimized check that should run most of the time a new number arrives
    /// </summary>
    static void CheckInCandidate(double currentNum)
    {
        arr[CurrentLocation] = currentNum;
        if (currentNum >= High)
        {
            HighLocation = CurrentLocation;
            High = currentNum;
        }
        else if (CurrentLocation == HighLocation)
            ReFindHighest();

        CurrentLocation++;
        //if (CurrentLocation == HistoryLength) CurrentLocation=0; //is this faster??
        CurrentLocation = CurrentLocation % LookBackPeriods; //is this faster??
        Console.WriteLine("Current:" + currentNum + "\tHighest of " + LookBackPeriods + "last is " + High); //for validation purposes only.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the above caching works much faster than the Ascending Minima algorithm.
the code below contains both algos with benchmarks (this version is for finding the lowest).

```
static class Program
{
    static Random r = new Random();
    static int Window = 1000; //(small to facilitate visual functional test). eventually could be 100 1000, but not more than 5000.
    const int FullDataSize =100000;//000;
    static double[] InputArr = new double[FullDataSize]; //array prefilled with the random input data.

    //====================== Caching algo variables
    static double Low = 0;
    static int LowLocation = 0;
    static int CurrentLocation = 0;
    static double[] Result1 = new double[FullDataSize]; //contains the caching mimimum result
    static int i1; //incrementor, just to store the result back to the array. In real life, the result is not even stored back to array.

    //====================== Ascending Minima algo variables
    static double[] Result2 = new double[FullDataSize]; //contains ascending miminum result.
    static double[] RollWinArray = new double[Window]; //array for the caching algo
    static Deque<MinimaValue> RollWinDeque = new Deque<MinimaValue>(); //Niro.Deque nuget.
    static int i2; //used by the struct of the Deque (not just for result storage)


    //====================================== my initialy proposed caching algo
    static void CalcCachingMin(double currentNum)
    {
        RollWinArray[CurrentLocation] = currentNum;
        if (currentNum <= Low)
        {
            LowLocation = CurrentLocation;
            Low = currentNum;
        }
        else if (CurrentLocation == LowLocation)
            ReFindHighest();

        CurrentLocation++;
        if (CurrentLocation == Window) CurrentLocation = 0; //this is faster
        //CurrentLocation = CurrentLocation % Window; //this is slower, still over 10 fold faster than ascending minima

        Result1[i1++] = Low;
    }

    //full iteration run each time lowest is overwritten.
    static void ReFindHighest()
    {
        Low = RollWinArray[0];
        LowLocation = 0; //bug fix. missing from initial version.
        for (int i = 1; i < Window; i++)
            if (RollWinArray[i] < Low)
            {
                Low = RollWinArray[i];
                LowLocation = i;
            }
    }

    //======================================= Ascending Minima algo based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/14823809/2381899 
    private struct MinimaValue
    {
        public int RemoveIndex { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }

    public static void CalcAscendingMinima (double newNum)
    { //same algo as the extension method below, but used on external arrays, and fed with 1 data point at a time like in the projected real time app.
            while (RollWinDeque.Count > 0 && i2 >= RollWinDeque[0].RemoveIndex)
                RollWinDeque.RemoveFromFront();
            while (RollWinDeque.Count > 0 && RollWinDeque[RollWinDeque.Count - 1].Value >= newNum)
                RollWinDeque.RemoveFromBack();
            RollWinDeque.AddToBack(new MinimaValue { RemoveIndex = i2 + Window, Value = newNum });
            Result2[i2++] = RollWinDeque[0].Value;
    }

    public static double[] GetMin(this double[] input, int window)
    {   //this is the initial method extesion for ascending mimima 
        //taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14823809/2381899
        var queue = new Deque<MinimaValue>();
        var result = new double[input.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var val = input[i];

            // Note: in Nito.Deque, queue[0] is the front
            while (queue.Count > 0 && i >= queue[0].RemoveIndex)
                queue.RemoveFromFront();

            while (queue.Count > 0 && queue[queue.Count - 1].Value >= val)
                queue.RemoveFromBack();

            queue.AddToBack(new MinimaValue { RemoveIndex = i + window, Value = val });

            result[i] = queue[0].Value;
        }

        return result;
    }

    //============================================ Test program.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { //this it the test program. 
        //it runs several attempts of both algos on the same data.
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Low = 12000;
            for (int i = 0; i < Window; i++)
                RollWinArray[i] = 10000000;
            //Fill the data + functional test - generate 100 numbers and check them in as you go:
            InputArr[0] = 12000;
            for (int i = 1; i < FullDataSize; i++) //fill the Input array with random data.
                //InputArr[i] = r.Next(100) + 11000;//simple data.
                InputArr[i] = InputArr[i - 1] + r.NextDouble() - 0.5; //brownian motion data.

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < FullDataSize; i++) //run the Caching algo.
                CalcCachingMin(InputArr[i]);

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Caching  : " + stopwatch.ElapsedTicks + " mS: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            stopwatch.Reset();


            stopwatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < FullDataSize; i++) //run the Ascending Minima algo
                CalcAscendingMinima(InputArr[i]);

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("AscMimima: " + stopwatch.ElapsedTicks + " mS: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            stopwatch.Reset();

            i1 = 0; i2 = 0; RollWinDeque.Clear();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < FullDataSize; i++) //test the results.
            if (Result2[i] != Result1[i]) //this is a test that algos are valid. Errors (mismatches) are printed.
                Console.WriteLine("Current:" + InputArr[i].ToString("#.00") + "\tLowest of " + Window + "last is " + Result1[i].ToString("#.00") + " " + Result2[i].ToString("#.00") + "\t" + (Result1[i] == Result2[i])); //for validation purposes only.

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```